# How to set the mode of port? access, trunk, general

Tags: vmware-esxi, port, switch, vlan, telnet

I tried to set (change) the mode of my port, and I read the book and followed it step by step. But I still get a lot of error.

There were what I input.

(Routing) (Interface 0/3)#switchport mode general

```
                                                              ^
```

(Routing) (Interface 0/6)#switchport mode access

```
                                       ^
```

(Routing) (Interface 0/6)#switchport mode trunk

```
                                       ^
```

All of the problems are Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

I search a lot, and everyone always says "switchport mode access/trunk/general", but I could not input it.

Why?

Comment: What model device is this?

Comment: @RonTrunk Croton+

Comment: use question mark or tab to see the options after switchport mode